# PHP pChart change color of slices of pie chart

Tags: php, charts, pchart

I am developing php pie chats with pChart, it looks nice. Now I want to change color of each slices. Is it possible to change the color?

Comment: The [`setColorPalette()`](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=faq.colors) function?

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is setSliceColor() - http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.pie.setslicecolor.html

Assuming you have created a new pie chart from some data:

```
$PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$MyData);
```

You can then use it like this:

```
$PieChart->setSliceColor(0, array("R" => 255, "G" => 0, "B" => 0));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(1, array("R" => 0, "G" => 255, "B" => 0));
etc...
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, at least for pChart 2.0.  Remember to do this BEFORE you call ->draw2DPie or whatever draw command you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

For pChart (almost all versions), you will just use this :

```
...
$PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$MyData);
$PieChart->setSliceColor(0,array("R"=>255,"G"=>128,"B"=>0));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(1,array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(2,array("R"=>25,"G"=>128,"B"=>0));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(3,array("R"=>55,"G"=>255,"B"=>25));
...
```

Just add more setSliceColor for more slice on your chart

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question just doing this:

```
  /* 
  Example 10 - A 3D exploded pie graph
  Version 1.27d pChart*/ 

  $Test->loadColorPalette('ColorsDirectory/tones-9.txt',',');
  $Test->drawPieGraph(
    $DataSet->GetData(),
    $DataSet->GetDataDescription(),
    350,130,110,PIE_PERCENTAGE_LABEL,FALSE,50,20,5);
...
```

Call **loadColorPalette** just before calling **drawPieGraph**. It works this way.Good luck!